# Semantic difference between one rule where conditions are seperated with ';' (or) and rules written down seperatly

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

Let `b`, `c` and `d` be facts or rules

```
x(A) :- b(A);c(A);d(A)
```

vs

```
x(A) :- b(A)
x(A) :- c(A)
x(A) :- d(A)
```

**Is there a difference in semantics between the two definition of the rule `x`** ? In my opinion I believe they are the same, because every rule of `x` can be interpreted as either the first rule of `x` or the second or third.

Comment: There is no difference, if the definition is `static` and `private`. In many systems that is the default. If not, either `clause(x(X), Body)` succeeds (with different answers for `Body`), or even `retract((x(any) :- b(any)))` succeeds in one case and fails in the other.